# convert PDL scalar to Perl scalar

Tags: perl, scalar, pdl

I have a function that uses `PDL`. The final step is a dot product so it returns a scalar. However, when I try to print this scalar, it is clearly still a piddle and prints like this on screen:

```
[
  [ 3 ]
]
```

I'm wondering how I can convert it back to the regular Perl scalar so that it prints like:

```
3
```

More importantly, what is the consequence if I don't convert and take that piddle on to further arithmetic manipulations in a pure Perl context (that does not involve PDL). Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `sclr` method, which converts a single-element PDL matrix with any number of dimensions into a simple Perl scalar

```
my $dotp = sclr($mata x $matb);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question ("what is the consequence if I don't convert and take that piddle on to further arithmetic manipulations in a pure Perl context (that does not involve PDL)"); there are two major considerations:

- PDL entities ("ndarrays") have overloaded arithmetic so that any Perl scalars used with them will get promoted, and the results will also be ndarrays. For scalar (single-element) ndarrays this is probably undesirable since PDL operations have a performance hit that isn't worth it for a single element
- the ndarray shown in the example has one element, but it is 2-dimension (1x1); to be a proper scalar ndarray, you'd do `$dotp->squeeze` to drop all length-1 dims